# SQL Query for mixing searchword and f.e. most-sold

Tags: sql, sqlite, search, sql-order-by

Hi im searching for an idea to mix searchresults (for jQuery autocompletion) by filtering by id, searched-word and most sold. I have "products" table which has following colums: "id,name,...,sold" Here my sql

```
    SELECT * FROM products
    WHERE 
        state=1 
        AND ( 
            id='$search' OR id LIKE '$search%' OR  id LIKE '%$search%' OR 
            name='$search' OR name LIKE '$search%' OR name LIKE '%$search%' 
            ) 
        ORDER BY ???
```

In this query is the "sold (sold-items)" not included. Im searching for way to combine this into my query too. 
I need this order

```
1. full id (e.g. sombody types 312 than the first row must be id=312)
2. full name (...)
3. otherwise search-pattern combined with "sold"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
SELECT p.*, 
       MAX(3 * (id = '$search' OR id LIKE '%$search%'),
           2 * (name LIKE '%312%'),
           1 * (sold LIKE '%312%')) rank 
  FROM products p
 WHERE state = 1 
   AND (id = '$search' OR id LIKE '%$search%'
    OR name LIKE '%$search%'
    OR sold LIKE '%$search%')
 ORDER BY rank DESC
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d89b9/3)** demo